# Is there a way to simplify if statements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, if-statement, simplify

I am trying to simplify mainly the if statements. As you can see, I colorize my text and this way works, but there is a lot of repetitive code in the if statements. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
const colorText = ( message, colorr ) => {
    let mesge = []


    for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++){

        //TRYING TO SIMPLIFY THIS CODE BELOW\\//TRYING TO SIMPLIFY THIS CODE BELOW\\
        //TRYING TO SIMPLIFY THIS CODE BELOW\\//TRYING TO SIMPLIFY THIS CODE BELOW\\
        if(i===0 || i===5 || i===10 || i===15 || i===20) {colorr[i] = colorr[0]}
        if(i===1 || i===6 || i===11 || i===16 || i===21) {colorr[i] = colorr[1]} 
        if(i===2 || i===7 || i===12 || i===17 || i===22) {colorr[i] = colorr[2]} 
        if(i===3 || i===8 || i===13 || i===18 || i===23) {colorr[i] = colorr[3]} 
        if(i===4 || i===9 || i===14 || i===19 || i===24) {colorr[i] = colorr[4]} 

       mesge[i] = (
        <span style={{ color: colorr[i]}}>
            {message[i]}
        </span>
       )

    }
    return mesge
    // console.log(message)
    // console.log(color)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with remnants of division (modulus through the symbol %). For example, 3% 2 returns the remainder of the division of 3 by 2, which in this case is 1. In your conditionals you are working with multiples of 5, numbers that leave remainder 1 in the division by 5, numbers that leave remainder 2 in division by 5 and etc ... That way the code would look like this:

```js
const colorText = ( message, colorr ) => {
    let mesge = []
    for (let i = 0; i < message.length; i++){
        colorr[i] = color[i % 5]
       mesge[i] = (
        <span style={{ color: colorr[i]}}>
            {message[i]}
        </span>
       )
    }
    return mesge
}
```

Comment: This is relative, it goes to the author of the answer. In my view for example I found it necessary due to the issue. Don't bother with it ;)

Comment: No, it's not relative. You repeated entire snippet and it's hard to find out what changed. But welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: @RoboRobok I respectfully disagree. This answer is the only one yet explaining what's going on and why it works.

Comment: @Junaid Razaq Good that appreciated the answer, good studies! :)

Answer (score 3):

How about using the [remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder):

```
colorr[i] = colorr[i % 5];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just take the value of the remainder with five.

```
colorr[i] = colorr[i % 5];
```

Comment: You mean `colorr[i] = colorr[i % 5]`.

Comment: @RoboRobok how come?

Comment: @evolutionxbox because that's what the original code does.